# Prevent class attributes from .toggleClass on load?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a jQuery script that uses the a `.toggleClass` button to toggle the visibility of `<tr>`s that contain `<td>`s with content. When the page loads, two elements should be visible:

1. `<tr>`s that contain `<td>`s **with** content
2. `<tr>`s that contain `<td>`s **without** content

The issue I'm having is that when the page loads, the class 'todo-assigned-empty' is loaded as well. How do I prevent 'todo-assigned-empty' from being active on load, and only become active when .toggleClass is clicked?

jQuery and CSS:

```
jQuery:

    $('#empty_items').on("click", function(e) {
        $('.todo-list:has(> .todo-assigned:parent)').toggleClass('todo-assigned-empty');
    });


CSS:

    .todo-assigned-empty {
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: I should admit i don't understand what you are talking about. Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: BTW, why just not didn't set class todo-assigned-empty then?

Comment: @roasted: I'll get a fiddle going. You mean not defining display:none? How would I hide the <tr>s then?

Comment: i mean not set class to elements in html, but like i told you, i don't really understand your problem here thats why setting a jsfiddle would help to understand your issue

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/wSQ7J/ The strange thing is that the code performs fine in the fiddle, it's when I load it on my site that the class is active on load. I want '.todo-assigned-empty' to NOT be active on load. So I'm guessing this is something I'd have to troubleshoot.